# js Как добавить в элемент div класс если в hash ссылки присутствует ?variant_id=

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно помощь с jS
Необходимо в div=mybox - добавить класс myhash, в том случае если в ссылке присутствует ?variant_id=196388413

Помогите кодом, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function getkey(key) {
        let p = window.location.search;
        p = p.match(new RegExp(key + '=([^&=]+)'));
        return p ? true : false;
    }
    
 if (getkey('variant_id'))  document.querySelector('#mybox').classList.add('myhash');
```